# Alert message for based on input value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a text adventure game.  I want the user the enter the command into the input.  If the command is known, I want an alert to pop up with the result.  This is what I have.

```
<input onchange="getValue(this)" id="type" type="text" placeholder="Enter a command"/>

var start = function getValue()
{
getElementById=("type").value;
}
if (getValue()==="Start") {
alert("Desert Run")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really improve your knowledge in javascript as now your syntax is totally wrong.

```
function getValue(el)
{
  if (el.value === "Start")
     alert("Desert Run")
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqRLY/)

Comment: That's not the only thing. The basic knowledge of/logical thinking in HTML is lacking as well: `id="type"`? And is it my perception, or does this mismatch between knowledge and difficulty of task often occur among wanna-be game makers?

Comment: @Frank Conijn : It can be noticed everywhere, actually, I guess it is a question of how popular this or that programming language is. There are a lot of silly question in php too, for example, as most of people get acquainted with server-side technics using  this language. And of course it is not a shame that somebody doesn't know something when he starts learning, but the shame is that with the first error they are posting their code here instead of using Google. The main thing that I can't understand is that this approach is much longer than just searching for the solution on your one.